# Tangent bundles of period domains of higher weight Hodge structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, symmetric-spaces

Considering $A_{g}$ the moduli space of principally polarized abelian varieties, there is a variation of Hodge structures $\mathbb{V}=E^{1,0}\oplus E^{0,1}$ of weight $1$ on $A_{g}$. It is well-known that the tangent bundle $T_{A_{g}}$ satisfies the equality: $T_{A_{g}}=S^{2}E^{0,1}$. Now my question is that what is the analogue of this equality for period domains of higher weight Hodge structures? More precisely, let $D=G/K$ be a period domain for Hodge structures of weight $k\geq 2$ which is a locally symmetric variety. Then can the tangent bundle $T_{D}$ be described in terms of symmetric powers of pieces of Hodge structures? How realizes one the analogue of the above equality in this case? I'll appreciate any useful reference.

Comment: Any book on Hodge structures (e.g. Carlson-Peters-Müller-Stach) will give you the answer. For a more rapid approach, see for instance §8 of [this fundamental paper](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/PMIHES/PMIHES_1970__38_/PMIHES_1970__38__125_0/PMIHES_1970__38__125_0.pdf) of Griffiths.